# GridSplitter not working after applying an animation to a grid column

Tags: wpf, animation, gridsplitter

I'm a beginner in wpf, today I come across an odd issue that the gridsplitter stops working if I add an animation to a grid column, below is the code snippet, it's a meaningless but quite simply test code, it does nothing except when the mouse enters the right column, the width of it will expand from 15 to 100

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="c1"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="c2" Width="15" MinWidth="15"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="Gray"></Border>
    <GridSplitter Width="8" Background="Yellow"></GridSplitter>
    <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Silver" Name="bdRight" MouseEnter="bdRight_MouseEnter"></Border>
</Grid>
```

and this:

```
        bool flag = true;
    private void bdRight_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            flag = false;
            var da = new GridLengthAnimation();
            da.From = new GridLength(c2.MinWidth);
            da.To = new GridLength(100);
            var ef = new BounceEase();
            ef.EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut;
            da.EasingFunction = ef;
            this.c2.BeginAnimation(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, da);
        }
    }
```

and here's the GridLengthAnimation, I get it from internet after I find that DoubleAnimation cannot be used against the width of grid column.

```
public class GridLengthAnimation : AnimationTimeline
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FromProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EasingFunctionProperty;

    static GridLengthAnimation()
    {
        FromProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("From", typeof(GridLength), typeof(GridLengthAnimation));
        ToProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("To", typeof(GridLength), typeof(GridLengthAnimation));
        EasingFunctionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EasingFunction", typeof(IEasingFunction), typeof(GridLengthAnimation));
    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new GridLengthAnimation();
    }

    public override Type TargetPropertyType
    {
        get { return typeof(GridLength); }
    }

    public IEasingFunction EasingFunction
    {
        get
        {
            return (IEasingFunction)GetValue(GridLengthAnimation.EasingFunctionProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(GridLengthAnimation.EasingFunctionProperty, value);
        }

    }

    public GridLength From
    {
        get
        {
            return (GridLength)GetValue(GridLengthAnimation.FromProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(GridLengthAnimation.FromProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public GridLength To
    {
        get
        {
            return (GridLength)GetValue(GridLengthAnimation.ToProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(GridLengthAnimation.ToProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public override object GetCurrentValue(object defaultOriginValue, object defaultDestinationValue, AnimationClock animationClock)
    {
        double fromValue = ((GridLength)GetValue(GridLengthAnimation.FromProperty)).Value;
        double toValue = ((GridLength)GetValue(GridLengthAnimation.ToProperty)).Value;

        IEasingFunction easingFunction = this.EasingFunction;

        double progress = (easingFunction != null) ? easingFunction.Ease(animationClock.CurrentProgress.Value) : animationClock.CurrentProgress.Value;

        if (fromValue > toValue)
        {
            return new GridLength((1 - progress) * (fromValue - toValue) + toValue, this.To.IsStar ? GridUnitType.Star : GridUnitType.Pixel);
        }
        else
        {
            return new GridLength((progress) * (toValue - fromValue) + fromValue, this.To.IsStar ? GridUnitType.Star : GridUnitType.Pixel);
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment out codes in the MouseEnter event handler, the splitter works fine, otherwise, it stops working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to set the [FillBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior.aspx) property of your animation. The default value is `HoldEnd`, which means that the animation holds the final value after it has ended. If you set FillBehavior to `Stop` the animated value will revert back to the value it had before beeing animated.

If you add the following lines to your event handler code, it should work as expected:

```
...
da.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
c2.Width = da.To; // set final value before starting the animation
c2.BeginAnimation(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, da);
```

---

In case setting the final value before starting the animation creates a flickering effect, you may instead set the final value in a `Completed` handler:

```
...
da.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
da.Completed += (s, e) => c2.Width = da.To;
c2.BeginAnimation(ColumnDefinition.WidthProperty, da);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on the earlier answer (would comment but not allowed by the stackoverflow overmaster):

For me, setting the final value before kicking off the animation generates an ugly flicker effect for my grid a split second before the animation kicks in.

What I did was to use the FillBehavior.Stop mentioned above but subscribe to the Animation.Completed event and set the final height of the grid column in there.

Works like a charm without any flickering.